# Facebook token Android SDK refresh criteria

Tags: android, facebook, access-token

I wished to understand the facebook refresh cycle for the long term access token (60 days).

Although their [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) implies

***If I make a graph '/me' call a day after obtaining the access token, the token expiry would be updated or extended***

but the same isn't the case. I tried querying the /me endpoint via their android SDK but the token expiry wasn't updated.

I came across a similar question [Facebook: refresh AccessToken on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369906/facebook-refresh-accesstoken-on-android) but the suggestion didn't work for me.

**Ps:**  Would be happy to share code but I doubt that is needed.

-------**EDIT**------

My use case involves only authentication at the client end , followed up with submitting the token to my server. This token is periodically used by my server to fetch updated user info. In order to accomplish this I need to ensure that the token never expires at the client. I don't wish to relogin the user on token expiry as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in the document you linked states:

> Facebook's official SDKs manage the lifetime of tokens for you. When
>   using iOS, Android or our JavaScript SDK, **the SDK will handle making
>   sure that tokens are refreshed before they expire.**

If you read through the documentation, you can see that if the user uses the app, the SDK will refresh your token daily. If the user has not used it in 60 days, then he has to log in again to get a new token.

Altogether, no action is required on your side for refreshing the token manually.
Why do you think you have to refresh the token?

Comment: The linked doc clearly suggests ' These tokens will be refreshed once per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook servers'  as opposed to purely using the app.  However in my use case, I use FB only for authentication at the client. The token is also passed to my server which maintains/uses this periodically. For this I need to ensure that the token never expires.

Comment: No, you need to make sure the server always has the latest access token ;)

Comment: The latest accesstoken can only be obtained on login post that unless a request is made the token doesn't refresh. Thats the part I wish to avoid and make the token  refresh transparent to the user without login.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: As @humblerookie notices, it doesn't seem to be the case that tokens are refreshed just because the app is _used_. Actual Graph API calls have to made from the app, and not just any Graph API calls (for example with a custom HTTP client), only calls made using Facebook SDK. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908098/1483676