# How should Facebook Login app implement the new 60- or 90-day login requirement?

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-access-token, android-facebook

Facebook sent out developer notification pointing to 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing:

The page contains 2 concerning portions:

> When you use iOS, Android, or our JavaScript SDK, the SDK will handle
>   making sure that tokens are refreshed before they expire during this
>   90-day period. Native mobile apps using Facebook's SDKs get long-lived
>   access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed
>   once per day, for up to 90 days, when the person using your app makes
>   a request to Facebook's servers. If no requests are made, the token
>   will expire after about 60 days and the person will have to go through
>   the login flow again to get a new token.

and

> Between April 9–21, 2018, tokens for users who have not actively
>   logged into your app and granted consent to permissions in the last 90
>   days will expire. To refresh these user tokens, you must send people
>   through the login process, and they must renew consent by clicking the
>   Continue button. Renewal of consent is now required every 90 days.

However, I don't get a clear picture of how one can make a simple update to an app that will implement this requirement. One thing that would not be simple, is to update every place you make a graph request with the SDK and catch the token expiration, assuming this is possible. I revisited the [documentation page for Facebook Login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing), to see if they updated it in regards to this access token policy change. But there is not update. I suppose also you could check at app startup to see if the current access token is 60 days old, and if so assume it needs to be manually refreshed with login.

I did see [AccessTokenTracker](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/accesstokens), I am not sure if it is called when access token expires, anyone knows?

Footnote: The only result on SO for `[android] [facebook] accesstoken refresh expires` is this. [Facebook token Android SDK refresh criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497021/facebook-token-android-sdk-refresh-criteria)